# log4net RollingFileAppender stops working after deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, log4net, log4net-appender

My aps.net core application is running fine and generating logs and rolling them each day, however as soon I deploy a new version of the app to IIS it stops logging and also stops rolling. It only starts again if I rename the current log file to something different. But then it works as expected again.

The deployment involves stopping the app by creating a `app_offline.htm` file in the apps root folder.

The app runs on dot.net core 2.2.8 and the log4net version is 2.0.10.

This is the condig for my RollingFileAppender

```
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="<some absolute path>\Log.txt"/>
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <datePattern value=" yyyy-MM-dd" />

    <threshold value="All" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <!--<conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger  - %message%newline" />-->
        <conversionPattern value="%property{log4net:HostName} %date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline%exception" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Any idea what might cause this behavior?

Windows logs:

In the windows logs I can find this error (but not always):

```
IISMANAGER_CRASH

IIS Manager terminated unexpectedly.

Exception:System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Cannot call disconnect on a proxy.
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.Disconnect(MarshalByRefObject obj, Boolean bResetURI)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.HostingEnvironmentShutdownComplete(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.HostingEnvironmentShutdownComplete(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost)
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.OnAppDomainUnload(Object unusedObject, EventArgs unusedEventArgs)

Process:InetMgr
```

I also noticed that a different application gets shutdown due to the deployment because it has the same physical root. Could this be the problem? Should I add a delay between shutting down the app (via creating `app_offline.htm`) and the deployment?

The part with the second app is also a difference to the development deployment (which does not have the problem).

Comment: Have you checked Windows event logs to see if the application is throwing any errors? Does an IIS reset work?

Comment: Since the IIS is also serving other websites a IIS reset is undesirable for the deployment process. However I haven't looked into windows event logs and will do it now.

Comment: @Xerillio see my update for an error log and some more details

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the second app that has the same physical address. Since it uses the same root folder it also uses the same log4net-config. This means that two processes want to log to the same file. Here comes the `LockingModel` from `FileAppender` into focus.

As the docs state

> [The default locking model is the `FileAppender.ExclusiveLock`.](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/P_log4net_Appender_FileAppender_LockingModel.htm)

And the docs for `FileAppender.ExclusiveLock` states

> [Open the file once for writing and hold it open until `CloseFile()` is called. Maintains an exclusive lock on the file during this time.](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Appender_FileAppender_ExclusiveLock.htm)

which causes two processes too fight over an exclusive look over the same file (and I would expect that if one process has the file opend it will only close it if the process ended (i.e. if IIS recycles it)).

The solution is to use the `FileAppender.InterProcessLock` which provides cross-process file locking.

To use it we just add this xml code to the appenders configuration:

```
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+InterProcessLock" />
```

Comment: Out of interest: why are you hosting 2 apps from the same folder?

Comment: @Xerillio I honestly don't now. I need to ask a college why it is setup the way it is.